# Recursive function for testing all links on the page

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am writing scraper links from all over the site, including subpages and encountered a small problem. I came up with the idea to use a recursive function because the page I want to scan has several levels. Its structure looks more or less like this:

```
Level 1 reference
- Second level reference
-- Third level reference
-- Third level reference
- Second level reference
-- Third level reference
-- Third level reference
-- Third level reference
--- Level four reference
```

It is never entirely clear whether there are more or less hidden under the tested link, hence I came up with the idea of a recursive function.

It takes a link to the main page, takes the first one and if the number of links in it is greater than one, it refers to the same function.

Unfortunately, something goes wrong and I get an empty whiteboard, how can I fix it?

```
function scanWebsite($url) {

        $html = file_get_contents($url);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
        $nodes = $xpath->query("/html/body//a");

        $output = [];

        foreach($nodes as $node) {

            $url = $node->getAttribute("href");

            if(count($nodes) > 1) {

                scanWebsite("http://samplewebsite.com" .$url);

            } else {

                if(preg_match("/\/title\/.*\//", $url)) {

                    array_push($output, $url);

                }

                continue;

            }

        }

        return $output;

    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(scanWebsite("http://samplewebsite.com"));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I haven't read it extensively, but just at a glance it seems that the recursive call not returning anything could be a problem.

Comment: You are not using the return value of ` scanWebsite("http://samplewebsite.com" .$url);
`

Comment: Okay. If the code inside the foreach loop executes, then `count($nodes) > 1` will always be true. The `scanWebsite` call in the if block theoretically returns an array, but you aren't assigning it to anything. The code in the else block will never execute. After you fix those problems, you need to consider the possibility of circular references. If you have links back to pages you have already crawled, you'll end up with infinite recursion.